# Establish rules

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value, integer-programming, binary-programming

I think the above constraint when the absolute value of the HW for 2 strings is less than the HD between those strings. Any thoughts on the proof, please?

Also, how do I make it a constraint if it's provable? It's not necessary that the explanation has to be in terms of HD and/or HW.

Comment: is $a$ fixed or variable, in other words, should the formulation be linear in $a$ or not?

Comment: Why the modification? are you not satisfied with the answer? If not, please make your question more specific.

Comment: argh a kid did this..I have to rewrite this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i$ be an indicator variable that can only take the value $1$ if bit $i$ flips from $0$ to $1$. You can model that with the constraints $x_i \leq b_i$ and $x_i \leq 1 - a_i$. To ensure at least one flip occurs, you add $\sum_i x_i \geq 1$.

You can do the same with a variable $y_i$ that can only take the value $1$ if bit $i$ flips from $1$ to $0$.

Comment: Sorry, what are $a_i$ and $b_i$?

Comment: @zzzzzazaza  $a_i$ is the i-th element of $a$, in your example $a=(1,1,1,1,0)$, so $a_5=0$

Comment: I am finding different constraints for $y_i$. It comes to $y_i \leq a_i$ and $y_i \leq 1 - b_i$.

Comment: Also for $y_i$ will it be $\sum_i y_i \geq 1$?

Comment: @zzzzzazaza your constraints for $y$ are correct, and yes, $\sum_i y_i \geq 1$